# Intercept the rendering and interaction of the desktop

Tags: c#, c++, windows, opengl, directx

Is it possible, without modifying the Windows OS, to have a piece of software intercept the rendering of the desktop, and modify it before it is displayed? For example, if I wanted to intercept it, and apply a fish-eye effect to my entire screen, would this be possible?

If so, how would I go about doing so? (Don't worry about the effects, was only an example, i merely need the interception side of things)

Also, I need to be able to intercept mouse clicks, and modify their position before Windows responds to the input.

If anyone has links to this, or similar projects in C# or C++, that would also be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. E.g. the WinAmp player does that. However that code is very unstable so be prepared to reboot if you try it.

Comment: Could you at all forward me on to an example of such code, or techniques? I can't find much with my searches.

Comment: Re example, I already mentioned WinAmp (and that's free software). I don't know if the code is publicly available. But the desktop background is just a window, which therefore can be subclassed. I guess subclassing is used because I think I recall that all the COM based "active desktop" stuff was removed in Vista or whenever. *Apparently*, just checking now with Spy++, it's an Explorer-process window of class SHELLDLL_DefView that is a child of some other Explorer window, that in turn is on top of the system's non-Explorer desktop window. Injecting code in Explorer is easy, shell extension.